# Add scaleline control to OpenLayers 3 map with unknown projection

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, scale-bar

I've a MapGuide map display with OpenLayers 3 like this:

```
var options = {
"minZoom": 0,
"maxZoom": 100,
"center": [mapInfos.center.x, mapInfos.center.y],
"extent": [mapInfos.extent.minX, mapInfos.extent.minY,   mapInfos.extent.maxX, mapInfos.extent.maxY]
};
var projectionUnit = mapInfos.projection.unit;
var projectionCode = mapInfos.projection.code;
var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: projectionCode,
  extent: [mapInfos.projection.extent.minX, mapInfos.projection.extent.minY, mapInfos.projection.extent.maxX, mapInfos.projection.extent.maxY],
  units: projectionUnit,
});
ol.proj.addProjection(projection);
options.projection = projectionCode
var imgMG = new ol.source.ImageMapGuide({
  url: me._agentUrl,
  useOverlay: true,
  useAsyncOverlay: true,
  metersPerUnit: me._metersPerUnit,
  params: {
    FORMAT: 'PNG',
    MAPNAME: me._mapName,
    behavior: 2,  
    SESSION: me._session
  },
  ratio: 2
});
var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: imgMG,
});
me._map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    shiftDragZoom: false,
    altShiftDragRotate: false,
    keyboard: false,
    pinchRotate: false,
    pinchZoom: false,
  }),
  controls: [],
  layers: [layer],
  target: me._options.target,
  view: new ol.View(options)
});
```

And when I want to add a scaleline control to my map like this:

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({
  "className": this._control.className,
  "units": "metric" //To do dynamically with the map projection units /!\
});
```

I've an error: "transform should be defined"

Have you an idea to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add custom coordinate transform functions to your projection using the `ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms` to work correctly with scale line.
Check this example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/wms-custom-proj.html). It deals exactly with your case.

Also cosider that if your projection is a known projection you may use the proj4js library and should reference all the necessary tasks for you.

Now as long as you know the projection code. Do the following

1. Download the proj4js library form [here](http://proj4js.org/)
2. Refernce the proj4-src.js file within your project
3. Declare your projection , so proj4js is aware of it like so
   `proj4.defs("EPSG:27562","+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs");`
4. Now you may use your new projection like so
   `var myProjection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27562');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but where can I find the transform calcul of a specific projection to EPSG:4326 ?
Have I to use proj4 transform ?

Comment: Do you know the projection code??? Or is it just a custom projection of you?? If you know the EPSG code I may guide you how to use the proj4js lib to do your job. If not you need to find the formula that tranforms the lon,lat to x,y of your  projection

Comment: I know the projection code, I have it from mapguide api. And in my parameter to create my map, i define the projection code of my map and the proj4js definition, for example :
              "proj4": {
                "alias": "EPSG:27562",
                "definition": "+proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs"
              }

Comment: I have edited my answer to guide you.

Comment: Have I to replace my new ol.proj.Projection to proj4.defs and add the proj4 projection to ol.proj.addProjection(proj4Projection) ?

Comment: no replace your new ol.proj.Projection with ol.proj.get('EPSG:27562'). but this has to be called once the lib is loaded and proj4.defs has been asigned. No nedd to call ol.proj.addProjection

Comment: It's ok, I've no error but I doesn't see my scaleline ...

Comment: declare the scaleline like so`var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({});`

Comment: no probs. glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my problem thanks to @palvos.
So, this is the functionnal code :

```
var csProj4 = this._projections.getProj4Of(this._projections.getFromProj4(projectionCode));

proj4.defs(csProj4.alias, csProj4.definition);

options.projection = projectionCode
options.extent = [mapInfos.extent.minX, mapInfos.extent.minY, mapInfos.extent.maxX, mapInfos.extent.maxY];

var imgMG = new ol.source.ImageMapGuide({
  url: me._agentUrl,
  useOverlay: true,
  useAsyncOverlay: true,
  metersPerUnit: me._metersPerUnit,
  params: {
    FORMAT: 'PNG',
    MAPNAME: me._mapName,
    behavior: 2
    SESSION: me._session
  },
  ratio: 2
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
  source: imgMG,
});

me._map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    shiftDragZoom: false,
    altShiftDragRotate: false,
    keyboard: false,
    pinchRotate: false,
    pinchZoom: false,
  }),
  controls: [],
  layers: [layer],
  target: me._options.target,
  view: new ol.View(options)
});
```

And for the scaleline :

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({});
map.addControl(scaleLineControl);
```